# Shortcut for "Collapse empty tag" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut for "Collapse empty tag" in Android Studio or how could set it in keymap?

```
<element></element>
```

Convert to

```
<element />
```

If I press "Alt + Enter" shows me that option, but I would like to access this option directly

[image]

:(

P.S. I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tag like:

```
<element></element>
```

and want to convert it to

```
<element/>
```

then the simplest way is to type a slash `/` within the opening `element` tag, i.e.

```
<element/></element>
       ^^
      ↑↑↑ type '/'
```

The IDE will automatically remove the closing `</element>` which results in:

```
<element/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2016.2, there is no support in IntelliJ IDEA for assigning shortcuts to individual intention actions directly. The Alt-Enter popup is the only way to access this action from the keyboard.